# ng-repeat not compiling directive inside table row

Tags: html, angularjs, compiler-errors, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this table that when you click on the table row this gets "expanded"(it actually slide another table row with the table's colspan), for this I built this angular directive

```
app.directive('dirt', function($compile){
return{
    restrict:'A',
    scope:{

    },
    replace: true,

    compile:function(element, attrs){


        element.next().children().children().hide();
        element.next().children().hide();
        var table = element.parent().parent();
        var colspan = table.find('tr:first > th').length;
        console.log(table.find('tr'))

        if(!attrs['compiled']){
            var tr = element.next();
            tr.children().attr('colspan', colspan);

            $compile(tr.children()); 
        }

        element.bind('click', function(){
            event.stopPropagation();
            element.next().children().slideToggle();
            element.next().children().children().slideToggle();    
        });
    }
}
});
```

it's called dirt, and you put it in the tr which you need to click to expand the next tr

something like this

```
    <tbody>
      <tr dirt>
        <td>123465</td>
        <td>A123</td>
        <td>7455</td>
        <td>MX</td>
        <td>US</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>75000</td>
        <td>7500</td>
        <td>784</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div style="width:100%;min-height:1px;background-color:yellow;float:left;">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <span style="font-size:60px;">A4</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
              <span>rklgjnrkelgtjnkelrtm;lremt;lermt;lremt;lermt</span>
              <br />
              rlgtjknrekltrmnekltmret;reltmklertmnkelrt
              <br />
              klgmkldgmnjklfdngmkldfng,mdfgn,dfmgndf,g
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I have this [The way is needed](https://plnkr.co/edit/rrQOq3rXR41AAz7i56Jh?p=preview)  to show how this works with only one set of tr, you just need to click on the first table row to expand it

The problem here is that when I try to use ng-repeat-start and end this happens

[plunkr failed](https://plnkr.co/edit/hxgVIDrXqlYWpJpdhSfk?p=preview)

**I don't know how to compiled the second row affected by the dirt directive so it can be recognized for the ng-repeat dir, hope you know something about**

thanks.

Comment: Answer the question Daniel, don effing edit it for your own purposes Daniel, nosy azz